# When exchanging a token on the Facebook API , does the old token expiry change?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't find this in the docs anywhere:

given the pseudocode :

```
token_a = '12345'
token_b = facebook_api.exchange_token( token_a )
```

does

1. token_a expires on the creation of token_b
2. token_a expires on the timestamp token_a originally expired at
3. token_a expires at a new, shorter time, relevant to the token_b creation

Comment: The answer should be 2 based on my current observation.

Comment: I agree that answer #2 seems to be what is happening - but I can't find the official docs.

Comment: Documentation wouldn't cover everything. Normally we didn't care about token_a if we got token_b.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the two scenarios,

- token_a is returned as token_b with new expiry
- token_a is invalidated if token_b is different

Comment: I expected that to happen, but it's not in production.  I accidentally called the same function twice in a unit test, and the original access token returned a new access token each time.  Each one of those 3 access tokens are valid.  I tried it in a loop, and generated multiple valid tokens.  Each token was still valid after the ones it generated were used too.  I checked their debugger ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token ) and they're all valid.  The only difference is that the expire_times and issued_ats are synced to the first token exchange.